# Talend Convert string to Float

Tags: converters, talend

I am using Talend to make an ETL project.
To convert my string to Double, i use Float.parseFloat(row4.Exportation2.trim())
This the error that it gives me.
This is how my data looks like "766,9997474" "1 345,43" in the exportation2 
Does anyone have an idea why ?

```
Démarrage du job ConvertString a 14:03 27/01/2017.
Exception in component tMap_1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23,4897452"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at last.convertstring_0_1.ConvertString.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(ConvertString.java:1553)
at last.convertstring_0_1.ConvertString.runJobInTOS(ConvertString.java:2075)
at last.convertstring_0_1.ConvertString.main(ConvertString.java:1932)
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3464
[statistics] connected
6|Royaume-Uni|BA|1971|23,4897452
[statistics] disconnected
Job ConvertString terminé à 14:03 27/01/2017. [Code sortie=1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems here :

- If you want to convert from String to Double you should use Double.parseDouble().
- "," is not the expected char : it should be "." :
  You will have to convert "," char to "." char : if your input comes from an excel or delimited file, you can set this option on the advanced settings of tFileInput component ("advanced separator"). Otherwise you should use `yourString.replaceAll(",", "."))`
- there is a non-standard space in the String that you should replace with `yourString.replaceAll(" ", ""))`

Comment: Hello, i did the replace thing only till now and i don't know how i can fix this result 1�527.18

Comment: There is a space in your input, so I guess you'll have to call twice the replaceAll method (one time for the comma, the other time for the space, to be replaced with "")

Comment: I did this    row3.Exportation2.replaceAll(",", ".").replaceAll(" ", "") but the result does not change 1�527.18 still the same

Comment: this space character in your result does not seem standard (�). If you can edit the source to delete it it will be simplier, otherwise try to copy paste it in the replaceAll method.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) but when i multiply the number by 1 million in the outputfile.csv  the result appears like this 2.3489745200000003E7 instead of 23489745.200000003
Can you please help me with this one

Comment: are you opening the file with excel ? if so, try to open it with another software (notepad, notepad++). I don't think this is a talend issue.

Comment: okey i have charged the table and it has the values in the correct display but when i search in the table the last recorded aren't saved in it. I use Mysql. I ve looked into the Talend Job with tlog row and it says i have 73 records while in the my sql Table i find 72 only. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Now this is not related with original question. Open a new question for a new problem.

Comment: Okey i just did :)

Answer (score -1):

To do so u can use so many fucntions in t_Map : 
`columnValue = columnValue.replaceAll("\\W","");`

`\w = Anything that is a word character`
`\W = Anything that isn't a word character (including punctuation etc)`
`\s = Anything that is a space character (including space, tab characters etc)`
`\S = Anything that isn't a space character (including both letters and numbers, as well as punctuation etc)

or if u want to ignore any thing other then a letter or a number u can use simply :

`.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")`